# SELECT the most occuring value PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table structure using postgres:

> tran_id (int), cust_id(int), movie(varchar(255))

Approximately the data is like this:

```
 tran_id    cust_id    movie
 -------    -------    --------
 1          1          Zootopia
 2          1          Zootopia
 3          1          Saw
 4          2          Fight Club
 5          2          Fight Club
 6          3          Avengers: End Game
 7          3          Avengers: End Game
 8          3          Avengers: End Game
 9          3          Iron Man
 10         4          Fight Club
 11         4          Fight Club
 12         4          Percy Jackson
 13         4          Space Jam
 14         5          Inception
 15         5          Inception
```

I want to query so that it will show favorite movie for each customer. The expected output is below:

```
cust_id     fav_movie
-------     -------------------
1           Zootopia
2           Fight Club
3           Avengers: End Game
4           Fight Club
5           Inception
```

This is my current script:

```
SELECT cust_id, movie, MAX(fav_movie) FROM 
(SELECT cust_id, movie, COUNT(movie) AS fav_movie FROM transaction
GROUP BY cust_id, movie
ORDER BY cust_id) A
GROUP BY cust_id, movie;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cust_id) cust_id, movie AS fav_movie
FROM "transaction"
ORDER BY cust_id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, movie) DESC;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Comment: This is more simple than before with cte, but maybe you could edit the answer so that you're querying from transaction table instead of cte? Perhaps it will be useful for others in the future. Thanks a lot, it helps me.

Answer (score 2):

I would first get the counts for each movie and then output the one with the highest count per customer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cust_id)
       cust_id, movie
FROM (SELECT cust_id, movie,
             count(*) AS c
      FROM transaction
      GROUP BY cust_id, movie) AS grouped
ORDER BY cust_id, c DESC;
```